# Select SQL records based on a tuple

Tags: sql

I intend to select all records in `PH` table which match with records in the `RU` table based on a tuple of three fields: `(f1, f2, f3)`.

I don't just want records containing `f1` and records containing `f2` and records containing `f3` but all of these three fields in a record.

What am I supposed to do? A join?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: `select * from PH join RU using(f1, f2, f3)`

Answer (score 1):

Use an `IN` condition with those three columns.

The following is standard ANSI SQL:

```
select *
from ph
where (f1, f2, f3) in (select r.f1, r.f2, r.f3
                       from ruh r)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here as your question lacks in details. But from what I can gather you probably need to use set operator `INTERSECT`. For example:

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM PH
INTERSECT
SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM RU;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a correlated subquery to check for matches in `RU`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    PH
WHERE
    EXISTS(
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            RU
        WHERE
            RU.f1=PH.f1 AND
            RU.f2=PH.f2 AND
            RU.f3=PH.f3
    );
```

Comment: Thank you very much TT, that's exactly I wanted